# How do I get the SVG icon used by the Azure portal for a given Azure resource type?

Tags: azure, svg

Let's say I have `"Microsoft.Storage/StorageAccounts"` as a value in some internal tooling.

I want to display the icon for the corresponding Azure service, like how is done in the Azure portal.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "All services", the three lines on the left nav.

[image: all services]

Open the browser console.

Run

```js
copy(`
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="resource"></div>
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" focusable="false"><use id="bruh" href="#FxSymbol0-01a"></use>
        <script>
            const icons = {
                ${
                    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a.fxs-sidebar-flyout-item-link"))
                    .filter(x => x.querySelector(" use[href^='#FxSymbol']"))
                    .map(x => [x.href, x.querySelector("use[href^='#FxSymbol']").href.baseVal])
                    .filter(x => x[0].toLowerCase().includes("resourcetype"))
                    .map(x => [x[0].match("resourceType/(.*)$")[1],x[1]])
                    .map(x => [decodeURIComponent(x[0]), x[1]])
                    .map(x => `"${x[0]}": "${x[1]}"`)
                    .join(",\n")
                }
            };
        
            setInterval(()=>{
                const next = Object.entries(icons)[Math.floor(Math.random()*(Object.values(icons).length))];
                const id = next[0];
                document.getElementById("resource").innerText = id;
                document.querySelector("#bruh").href.baseVal = next[1];
            },500);
        </script>

            ${document.querySelector("#FxSymbolContainer").outerHTML}
            ${document.querySelector("#DefsContainer").outerHTML}
            ${document.getElementsByClassName("MsPortalImpl/Base/Base.Images.css")[0].outerHTML}

    </body>
</html>
`)
```

This will give you the content that you then paste into a local `whatever.html` file.

The Azure portal has a block of SVG definitions, and any instances where the portal uses service icons it uses SVGs that just point to the definition

[image: element picker showing reference]

By copying the SVG definitions and the relevant styling elements, we can embed the icons using the exact code that Azure uses to render them.

Open that file in your browser to view the demo. It will cycle through random resource providers and show the corresponding icons. The generated code includes a mapping from resource type to the SVG identifier used by Azure that we replicated.

[image: cycling icon demo]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to download, you can manually extract these icons directly from the Azure Architecture center which offers these icon downloads as SVGs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/icons/